# Software for Ubuntu with 3018 laser

Tags: software-recommendation

I hope you do ''t mind me asking as it is a bit a shot into the dark....
Is anyone aware of software running on Ubuntu which could drive a laser module on a prover 3018 CNC machine. I use Candle for milling, which works well. Laser Grbl is the recommended software for laser, but this isn't available for Unix.
Thanks

Comment: Which release? What does `lsusb` show? `sudo lshw` , `sudo journalctl  -b 0`, and page through to see how your system starts, and detects your device.

Comment: Their website claims "Linux support", "based on the open source Grbl ...". What more do you need?

Comment: Thank you @waltinator. if you mention "Their website"is that Laser Grbl?
Anyway, I worked around to create a conversion programme for code generated by InkScape (.gcode or .ngc) into a  .nc file. Even GRBL is not everywhere the same..
It solves my problem for now. So many thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

waltinator, thank you for your response. If you say "Their website" is that lasergrbl?
Anyway I worked around to take inkscape and created a conversion macro to convert  a.gcode file or an .ngc file into an (simplere) .nc file. So far it seems to work.

Again. Thank you for your answer.

H.